# Get coordinates of a place using Wikidata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sparql, wikidata

I am using Wikidata API to get birth location from famous people, and then displaying the location using Google Maps API. Here is the Wikidata request I use :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel WHERE {
  ?item (wdt:P31|wdt:P101|wdt:P106)/wdt:P279* wd:Q482980 ;
        rdfs:label "Mary Wollstonecraft"@en ;
        wdt:P19 ?birthLocation
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

I'm then using a google geocoder to get a lat lng from the birthLocationLabel, and displaying it on the map, however sometimes the geocoder can't find a location (maybe the place doesn't exist anymore), so I'd like to know if it was possible to get coordinates from the wikidata query ? I know birth location has a "coordinate location" property, but I don't know how to access it.

[image]

Here is the link of the  [wikidata query](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FbirthLocation%20%3FbirthLocationLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%28wdt%3AP31%7Cwdt%3AP101%7Cwdt%3AP106%29%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ482980%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Mary%20Wollstonecraft%22%40en%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP19%20%3FbirthLocation%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me `?birthLocation wdt:P625 ?coordinates` so the whole query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?coordinates ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel 
WHERE {
  ?item ((wdt:P31|wdt:P101|wdt:P106)/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q482980;
    rdfs:label "Mary Wollstonecraft"@en;
    wdt:P19 ?birthLocation.
  ?birthLocation wdt:P625 ?coordinates.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

This returns:

```
[{
    "item": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q101638",
    "itemLabel": "Mary Wollstonecraft",
    "coordinates": "Point(-0.075 51.5166)",
    "birthLocation": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q123219",
    "birthLocationLabel": "Spitalfields"
}]
```